# .NET Streamed PDF not opening in mobile browsers

Tags: ios, .net, pdf, mobile, stream

I have a dynamically generated pdf file hosted on a .NET 4.0 website that I stream to the users browser with this code (stream is the pdf file):

```
    byte[] ba = stream.ToArray();
    stream.Close();


    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.BinaryWrite(ba);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();
```

Recently we noticed this page had stopped working on iOS and Android devices. The download silently fails on android, but on iOS I get the following error:

Safari cannot open the page. The error was: 
"The operation couldn't be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)".

The only thing I can find for that error code is something about a malformed URL. I do have a hyphen in my base URL, and a question mark for the QueryString used to open the dynamic PDF, but I don't see any way around either of those, and besides I'm not sure that's causing the error.  My URL would look something like this:

```
https://www.mysite-20.tv/myfolder/QuoteToPDF.aspx?QuoteID=1134
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also add the Content-Length header, it helps in some situations.

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", ba.Length.ToString());
```

Comment: Nice! That got it. I was about to give up and save them all as files and serve them out statically. We try to avoid that with dynamic content though.  Thanks!

Comment: same issue exists in my site too, I already have given what u said though. Is there any other possible way to tackle this